# javascript 4 buttons, 2 work

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I have 4 image tags with the `id`'s of:

- `picture_off`
- `picture_on`
- `go_forward`
- `go_backward`

`picture_off` and `picture_on` when clicked work. However, `go_forward` is supposed to, when clicked, to make a div containing text `id="PageOneText"` disappear. This does not work.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#picture_off").click(function () {
            $("#MinecraftVideo").animate({
                opacity: '1.0'
            });
        $("#Floating_Island").animate({opacity: '0'});
        $("#picture_on").animate({opacity: '1'});
        $("#picture_off").animate({opacity: '0'});
        $("#attribute1").animate({opacity: '0'});
        $("#attribute2").animate({opacity: '1'});
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#picture_on").click(function () {
            $("#MinecraftVideo").animate({
                opacity: '0'
            });
        $("#Floating_Island").animate({opacity: '1'});
        $("#picture_off").animate({opacity: '1'});
        $("#picture_on").animate({opacity: '0'});
        $("#attribute1").animate({opacity: '1'});
        $("#attribute2").animate({opacity: '0'});
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#go_forward").click(function () {
            $("#PageOneText").animate({
                opacity: '0.0'
            });
        $("#go_forward").animate({opacity: '0'});
        $("#go_backward").animate({opacity: '1'});
        });
    });
```

Comment: There's no need for the multiple document.ready functions; just register your handlers in the same document.ready function. It's not an absolute and for large projects that's not the way to do it but for sure, you don't want to have a separate document.ready function for each handler!

Comment: Post a JSFiddle example

Comment: Incomplete information provided. Lacking HTML source for problem hunting.

Comment: Also, there' no need to use .animate() if all you're animating is the opacity; simplify your code with .fadeIn() and .fade() instead. There's nothing in the code you posted that could cause an issue so the problem is elsewhere. Is every ID unique?

Comment: cheers guys...to be honest I have only been beginning to code with javascript yesterday. Will try out your suggestions.

Comment: As @frenchie said, there isn't really a need for animate(),,... You could even just use the simple .show() and .hide() for your needs I believe. $("#picture_off").show(); etc

Comment: @frenchie Or just use CSS transitions to take advantage of hardware acceleration.

Comment: Works fine to me https://jsfiddle.net/mytg84ev/2/

Answer (score 0):

Chaps, thank you. Problem solved. Apparently it wasn't javascript error.

What I had done was used CSS to overlap two images with the exact dimensions. I moved the x value of one of them by 40px and huzzah! It all worked fine.

Thank you for your help and suggestions.